# Add a "Customize" link to left navigation in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, admin

I'm working on a theme for WordPress and I'd like to add a link in the left navigation that points to the "customize" feature that is built into WordPress.

The only way I know of in WordPress to get to that panel is to go to Appearance > Themes and then click the "Customize" text link next to the theme screenshot. That seems really hidden for an average user.

I'd like to put a text link under "Appearance" that points to that panel. The link that WordPress uses to get there is:

mydomain.com/wp-admin/customize.php

This needs to be in the theme's files, not hacking the WordPress core.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to state the obvious but the only way you can do this would be to modify the core.
Or possibly add it as a shortcut link in the top black nav bar / dashboard area

I've modified the admin before and it's not unheard of to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that plugins add menu items all the time, and so do custom post types, without modifying the core. I assumed there was some code to create a link in WordPress.

Comment: Until I find a better solution my work around has been to add an info box in the theme's settings page that explains what the live edit feature is and how to get to it.